# Monorail, nhibernate and session-per-request pattern

Tags: nhibernate, castle-monorail, session-per-request

I need some insights and thoughts about a refactoring I'm about to do to our web-app.

We initially used the session-per-request pattern with NHibernate and ActiveRecord by using the On_BeginRequest / On_EndRequest in the HttpApplication to create and dispose the session. Later on, we realized that any DB-related exceptions got thrown outside of our monorail-context, meaning that our rescues didn't kick in. As another sideeffect, we didn't have the option to fully skip creation of NHibernate sessions in any action, which in some cases would be desirable.

So we rewrote it to create sessions in Initialize() / Contextualize() in our base controller, and disposed them in the Dispose() of our base controller. We also Rollback the session in our rescue controller to prevent any half written changes to the DB. So far, so good. The reason for doing it in the Dispose() is because we want it to live through the view-rendering, because of lazy-loading reasons aswell as viewcomponents that needs to get a session (we could switch to units-of-work for the viewcomponents, but they don't seem to have a Dispose()...)

However, I'm experiencing some deadlock issues where we have started transacations in the DB that isn't getting rollbacked nor committed and I can't get my head around it, mostly because of the mess we've made with this approach...

So I found this article: http://hackingon.net/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request-with-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

And I thought, "Filters, we can use that in MonoRail too!", because it can kick in on BeforeAction and AfterRendering.

My questions then are:

1. What happens if an Exception occurs in the filter?
2. Will AfterRendering fire even if an Exception occurs in the action or the rendering?
3. Would you recommend this approach, if not, what are your suggestion instead?

Any pointers are very much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using the NHibernate facility?

Comment: We are using the ActiveRecordFacility, but I don't feel comfortable with the TransactionScope-way because I have no idea about the sessions created or disposed. I just rather have my own wrapper that uses the sessionFactory and creates session upon need. I'm hoping that I would be able to implement "session-per-request" and "unit-of-work" patterns in the same wrapper. How would the NHibernate facility help me in this scenario?

Comment: sorry, didn't see the mention of ActiveRecord. Yes, it's either the ActiveRecordFacility or the NHibernateFacility, not both. As for transactions, have you tried the Automatic Transaction Management Facility?

Comment: I know that we have tried it, but I can't see any mention of it in configuration, so I'm guessing we removed it. However, I'm trying to avoid to much black magic because I feel that we have lost track on the actual flow of our sessions. We also want to migrate away from active record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need an application error handler to care of exception handling.
2. Attach a debugger and find out.
3. Probably not (even though it is my article). It doesn't work with RenderAction. Best to use an IoC container to control the lifetime of connections.